# Wireshark cannot see traffic from a VirtualBox guest on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, wireshark

I have been trying to use Wireshark to capture some traffic that comes from a virtual machine.

The setup is:

- Windows 7 host
- Ubuntu guest
- VirtualBox 4

I send some packets from the guest to the host or another IP in the host LAN. The packets get there, but Wireshark cannot see them.

I have run Wireshark on both the guest and the host. Curiously, if I send the packet to another computer, the packets are captured without problem in the second machine. I don't understand how I cannot capture the packets in the machine that is sending them.

How should I setup VirtualBox, Windows 7 or Wireshark in order to capture the packets sent by the guest machine?

Comment: You can try if the following works out for you: [Wireshark under virtualbox broken after version 4](http://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=41831&start=0)

Comment: @slhck that is for running wireshark in the guest, he wast to know why it is not capturing on the host.

Comment: @santiagozky - answer should be changed.  Wireshark now supports this, but there are software bugs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When guest OS is set up, a network interface is assigned to it.
        Is wireshark listening on that interface?
In linux, there is an option to use "any" interface, which listens on all possible network interfaces, but I don't know if such option exists on the windows.

[Here](http://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/Loopback) is explained that wireshark in  windows has difficulties listening on loopback interface, the interface used when machine sends messages to it self.

Comment: the link explaining the loopback problem in windows was very helpful.

Comment: This is fixed on Wireshark now.  See my answer.

Answer (score 5):

Configure the `Attached to:` combo box to `Bridged Adapter` and set the `Promiscuous Mode:` combo box to `Allow All.`

Having done this I'm now seeing all traffic going to/from the guest OS.

Comment: This definitely did it

Answer (score 2):

I have an idea for solve your issue , too late but hope it help somebody else:)

Create Host-Only Adapter and bridge with your LAN Adapter. run wireshark on LAN Adapter, It will do the work

Answer (score 1):

In my experience Wireshark only sees the host's really external network interfaces. For example, if you use a web browser to look at a web page served by a web-server on the same PC (http://localhost), you can't use Wireshark to look at this traffic.

Similarly, the delivery of data by the VM to the host is local and not directed through a physical NIC. Presumably this provides no structure in the host operating system that looks like a "network interface" to Wireshark.

Comment: As explained "here"(http://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/Loopback) Windows do have problem listening on loopback interface (one used when browsing the localhost), but when wireshark is used on the linux, there are no such limitations

Answer (score 0):

As of March 18, 2022, Wireshark can capture traffic on the Loopback interface.  There is a dashboard when the application opens with a list of network interfaces.  Double click on "Adapter for Loopback Traffic Capture".
Wireshark needs to use the npcap packet capture library for loopback traffic to be detected.